# From "reduce input records" to "reduce input groups"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

After runing a MapRed job, we will get some summary about the job, for example:

```
...
reduce input records: 10
reduce input groups: 3
...
```

I knows this is caused by combine repeated keys. My question is what is the method that are used by reducer to combine records? key1.equals(key2) or key1.hashCode==key2.hashCode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only compareTo since keys have to implement [WritableComparable](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html).
`key.hashCode()` is used for partitioning reasons. Equals won't ever be used.

Answer (score 1):

Reducers do not, in general, combine records. One reducer is executed for each key emitted from the mappers (not necessarily in parallel).

Reduce Input Groups is the number of unique keys fed into the
reducers. Reduce Input Records is the number of values. Each key has
one or more values associated with it coming into the reducer.